# How to move web app data between farms

Tags: web-application, sql, sharepoint-farm

I have SharePoint Prod and Sharepoint Dev farm envirenment,
In my SharePoint Dev I have already "Site1b" an older copy of webapp 
"Site1a" from Prod
and I would like to update it How should I proceed?

Comment: I am assuming site1a is your site collection in Prod and you want overwrite site1b in dev, Correct? are you want just move the missing data from site 1a to 1b?

Comment: Site1a is the site on the Prod yes,I would prefer just move missing data because site B has another name/URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Back–up content database from the Source SP2010 SQL server and restore it in Destination SP 2010 SQL Server.
2. Make Sure that the new Content DB has corect permissions (read & write).
3. In SharePoint Central Admin create a new WebApplication, (e.g. ttp://application/sitename.
4. Open SharePoint Management Shell and run the command

   Test-SPContentDatabase -name  -webapplication http://application/sitename
5. This command will check the compatibility of the web application with the restored content database.
6. In SharePoint Central Admin, Navigate to Content Database settings, and remove any existing Content Databases associated with the Web Application http://application/sitename.
7. Now that you have a Web Application without a content database, you can now Mount the restored content database and attach it to the web Application.

   Mount-SPContentDatabase  -DatabaseServer  -WebApplication http://application/sitename
8. After the migration completes, then you can configure User profile service for the newly created web application.
9. Finally you can deploy your custom web part, custom master page, timer job.

Source:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0f1b3965-6f44-479b-9c86-0d9c5b72047e/copy-sharepoint2010-webapplication-from-one-sharepoint-server-to-another-sharepoint-server?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Almost I am using SharePoint2013 but  with your suggestion I could find solution on. http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/02/07/back-up-content-database-from-sharepoint-2010-and-restore-it-to-sharepoint-2013.aspx